# Creating a virtual webcam from jpeg using GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer, webcam, pipeline, gst-launch

I'm trying to use a jpg-File as a virtual webcam for Skype (or similar). The image file is reloading every few seconds and the Pipeline should also transmit always the newest image.
I started creating a Pipeline like this

```
gst-launch filesrc location=~/image.jpg ! jpegdec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! freeze ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video2
```

but it only streams the first image and ignores the newer versions of the image file. I read something about concat and dynamically changing the Pipeline but I couldn't get this working for me.

Could you give me any hints on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic refresh the input file is NOT possible (at least with `filesrc`).
Besides, your sample use `freeze`, which will prevent the image change.

One possible method is using `multifilesrc` and `videorate` instead.
`multifilesrc` can read many files (with a provided pattern similar to scanf/printf), and `videorate` can control the speed.

For example, you create 100 images with format image0000.jpg, image0001.jpg, ..., image0100.jpg. Then play them continuously, with each image in 1 second:

```
gst-launch multifilesrc location=~/image%04d.jpg start-index=0 stop-index=100 loop=true caps="image/jpeg,framerate=\(fraction\)1/1" ! jpegdec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! videorate ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video2
```

Changing the number of image at `stop-index=100`, and change speed at `caps="image/jpeg,framerate=\(fraction\)1/1"`
For more information about these elements, refer to their documents at gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugins.html

EDIT: Look like you use GStreamer 0.10, not 1.x
In this case, please refer to old documents [multifilesrc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/0.10.31/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-multifilesrc.html) and [videorate](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/0.10.36/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-videorate.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a general file name with `multifilesrc` if you add some parameter adjustments and pair it with an `identity` on a delay.  It's a bit fragile but it'll do fine for a temporary one-off program as long as you keep your input images the same dimensions and format.

`gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc loop=true start-index=0 stop-index=0 location=/tmp/whatever ! decodebin ! identity sleep-time=1000000 ! videoconvert ! v4l2sink`

Comment: Can you provide any examples of the general file name working @mpr?  Were you providing a list, or directory?  Can you please paste more or elaborate on this answer?

I would get 

`gstmultifilesrc.c(474): gst_multi_file_src_create (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMultiFileSrc:multifilesrc0:
Error reading file '/home/pi/Data/Videos/TimeLapse/12_10_18': Is a directory
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.`

If I tried *.jpeg added to the directory, that would also break.  Just looking for a pipeline recipe!

Comment: For the sake of completeness per comment above, I found that Gstreamer does accept symlinks.   So getting a variation this working to pre-process will work great:

`mkdir tmp
curIdx=0; for curFile in  *.JPG; do  outFile=$(printf "./tmp/img_%04d.jpg" "$curIdx"); echo 'File: '$curFile '->' $outFile; ln -s $curFile $outFile; curIdx=$(expr $curIdx + 1); done`

Reference: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1038158/jetson-tx2/gstreamer-h265-compression-jetson-tx2/